# Internal Server Error. I have issues when logging into wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.

I checked on the internet, everyone asks login to word press. but the same error above occurs when I log in. Can anyone please help me? I am stuck with my work.

I had changed the permalink of the site. after that, the problem occurred. Is there any way to change it without logging?

Comment: There can be a number of reasons for Internal Server Error. You should find the issue from the error logs on your server. If you are not sure where to find them, contact the support of your hosting company.

Comment: This question is extremely vague and cannot be answered based on the details provided. Please learn [how to ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise your question if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can really be a number of issues, but these are paramount.

1. .htaccess problems
2. A plugin you are using
3. Your hosting provider.

SOlution:

1. Access your hosting platform via FTP(Cpanel) and rename your current .htaccess(you must set hidden files to show in cpanel to see .htaccess) file to .htaccess-backup. then try logging in, WP will generate a new .htaccess.
   If this does not work.
2. Rename your plugins folder to 'plugins.backup' and try logging in again. If you get to login, the problem is with one of your plugins. Reactivate your plugins one after the other and watch its effect.
3. Talk to your host.